# Emgucv Image to texture2d on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, emgucv

```
public class testEmguCV : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Capture capture;

    void Start() 
    {
        capture = new Capture();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryGrayFrame();
        Bitmap bitmapCurrentFrame = currentFrame.ToBitmap();
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        bitmapCurrentFrame.Save(m, bitmapCurrentFrame.RawFormat);

        Texture2D camera = new Texture2D(400, 400);
        if (currentFrame != null)
        {
            camera.LoadImage(m.ToArray());
            renderer.material.mainTexture = camera;
        }
     }
}
```

I used above code to convert between camera feed from emgucv camera to texture2d in unity but i am having problem with `bitmapCurrentFrame.Save(m, bitmapCurrentFrame.RawFormat);` 
it is giving following errors

> ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   encoder System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.IO.Stream stream,
>   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo encoder,
>   System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encoderParams)
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save (System.IO.Stream stream,
>   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format) (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Image:Save
>   (System.IO.Stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat)
>   WebcamUsingEmgucv.Update () (at Assets/WebcamUsingEmgucv.cs:51)

After several hours of thinking and searching i dont know what is going on please help

Comment: I am having the exact problem, did you solved it?

Comment: I solved the problem by using the system.drawing.dll from Unity installation folder.
previously I was using system.drawing.dll from Windows folder that causes error.

Answer (score 0):

I used your example in our project, thanks! But i modified it to :

```
void Update()
{
    if(capture == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Capture is null");
        return;
    }
    Image<Gray, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryGrayFrame();
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
    currentFrame.Bitmap.Save(m, currentFrame.Bitmap.RawFormat);

    Texture2D camera = new Texture2D(400, 400);
    if (currentFrame != null)
    {
        camera.LoadImage(m.ToArray());
        renderer.material.mainTexture = camera;
    }
}
```

And it is work! Fps average ~30-35. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:
https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/blob/3ceb85cba71cf957d5e31ae0a70da4bbf746d0e8/Emgu.CV/PInvoke/Unity/TextureConvert.cs
it has something like this:

```
public static Texture2D ImageToTexture2D<TColor, TDepth>(Image<TColor, TDepth> image, bool correctForVerticleFlip)
     where TColor : struct, IColor
     where TDepth : new()
  {
     Size size = image.Size;

     if (typeof(TColor) == typeof(Rgb) && typeof(TDepth) == typeof(Byte))
     {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(size.Width, size.Height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        byte[] data = new byte[size.Width * size.Height * 3];
        GCHandle dataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        using (Image<Rgb, byte> rgb = new Image<Rgb, byte>(size.Width, size.Height, size.Width * 3, dataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()))
        {
           rgb.ConvertFrom(image);
           if (correctForVerticleFlip)
              CvInvoke.cvFlip(rgb, rgb, FLIP.VERTICAL);
        }
        dataHandle.Free();
        texture.LoadRawTextureData(data);
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
     }
     else //if (typeof(TColor) == typeof(Rgba) && typeof(TDepth) == typeof(Byte))
     {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(size.Width, size.Height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        byte[] data = new byte[size.Width * size.Height * 4];
        GCHandle dataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        using (Image<Rgba, byte> rgba = new Image<Rgba, byte>(size.Width, size.Height, size.Width * 4, dataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()))
        {
           rgba.ConvertFrom(image);
           if (correctForVerticleFlip)
              CvInvoke.cvFlip(rgba, rgba, FLIP.VERTICAL);
        }
        dataHandle.Free();
        texture.LoadRawTextureData(data);

        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
     }

     //return null;
  }
```

If You don't want tuo use an InterOp You can use also something like

```
cameraframe.Convert<Rgb,byte>().Data.Cast<byte>().ToArray<byte>()
```

and use it instead of section using interOp

Both solutions worked for me. Just remember to destroy the texture before replacing it. I had memory leak issues before I did that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JoshBurgess  Sorry,  I fixed the post.